# Install / Configure RevolutionAnalytics / RHadoop on Windows 7 & hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, rhadoop

I have installed VMware Player & Hortonworks Sandbox for Hadoop. Now I need help to configure / run RHadoop on that. I need to work with R and Hadoop. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the RHadoop wiki [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Downloads)

To get deeper in this integration, I recommend to you to see the **RHadoop** webinar at **Revolution Analytics** site [here](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/news-events/free-webinars/2011/r-and-hadoop/)

And for a quick guide how to install it, see first the great blog post at **Cloudera** [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/02/how-to-resample-from-a-large-data-set-in-parallel-with-r-on-hadoop/) and then follow the guide [here](https://github.com/cloudera/poisson_sampling/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

This guide is focused on Cloudera Hadoop Distribution on CentOS but you can adapt it easily to work with **Hortorworks Sandbox**.